# How to create Seq No for repeating rows from Select query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called Test with some repeating rows with column called Col1. The Sequence will reset to 0 when hit A. I want to create a sequence no as Result something like below:

```
Col1:
A
B
B
B
A
B
B
B
B
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
4
```

-- query I have used

```
SELECT COL1, CASE COL1 WHEN 'A' THEN '0' ELSE TO_CHAR(ROWNUM-0) END AS RESULT 
FROM TEST
```

Only will generate:

Result:

```
0
2
3
4
0
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `col1` is ordered like this in your question so there must be some criteria based on which this order is defined. Lets say the criteria is `PK` column.

So I am considering that there is column `PK` based on which `col1` is ordered as seen in your question.

You can use following query:

```
Select col1, 
       row_number() over (partition by sum_A order by col1) - 1 as result 
from
  (Select col1, 
          sum(case when col1 = 'A' Then 1 END) over (order by PK) as sum_A
   from test)
```

[DB<>FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ed10fb8f36e68f61bbde11ee329433d)

Cheers!!

Comment: It give me this error:  ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification
30485. 00000 -  "missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification"
*Cause:    Either the ORDER BY expression is mandatory for this function, or
           there is an aggregation group without any ORDER by expression.
*Action:
Error at Line: 33 Column: 8

Comment: Created a new column  for the order criteria.

Comment: Added End keyword. Many Thanks!!

Comment: sum(case when col1 = 'A' Then 1 END) over (order by PK) as sum_A

Answer (score 2):

As Tejash has pointed out, rows in a SQL table do not have any intrinsic order. The database is allowed to return rows in any order it chooses unless you `ORDER BY` something. Like Tejash, I am using a unique key to order the rows; people often use a date column for ordering if it exists.

Before database version 12c:

```
with data(pk, col1) as (
  select 00, 'A' from dual union all
  select 01, 'B' from dual union all
  select 02, 'B' from dual union all
  select 03, 'B' from dual union all
  select 04, 'A' from dual union all
  select 05, 'B' from dual union all
  select 06, 'B' from dual union all
  select 07, 'B' from dual union all
  select 08, 'B' from dual
)
Select pk, col1, 
  row_number() over (partition by grp order by pk) - 1 as result 
from (
  Select pk, col1,
    sum(case when col1 = 'A' Then 1 else 0 end) over (order by PK) as grp
  from data
);
```

Starting with version 12c:

```
with data(pk, col1) as (
  select 00, 'A' from dual union all
  select 01, 'B' from dual union all
  select 02, 'B' from dual union all
  select 03, 'B' from dual union all
  select 04, 'A' from dual union all
  select 05, 'B' from dual union all
  select 06, 'B' from dual union all
  select 07, 'B' from dual union all
  select 08, 'B' from dual
)
select * from data
match_recognize(
  order by pk, col1
  measures count(b.*) as result
  all rows per match
  pattern (a b*)
  define a as col1 = 'A',
    b as col1 = 'B'
);
```

Comment: Your second query is interesting but not working. can you please look into it? [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=185087ceef60a2d6e36bd16d9179fdf9)

Comment: Tejash, your link was to Oracle 11; choose 18 and it will work.

Comment: Tejash, look at the text just before the second query:
"Starting with version 12c:"
So your question was answered before you asked it.